# For está tirando o restante das variáveis da amostra no R

Tags: r, for

Estou fazendo uma amostra e o tamanho dela está em uma planilha chamada "tamamostra". Quando utilizo o comando for, como abaixo, a amostra é feita, porém, aparece somente a primeira coluna para cada amostra, eu gostaria que aparecesse toda a base de dados para cada amostra.

```
bons1<-0
for(i in 2:14){
bons1[i]<-subset(bons,data==tamamostra[1,i]) 
[sample(nrow(subset(bons,data==tamamostra[1,i])), tamamostra[3,i]), ]
}
```

Quando faço sem o for, 1 a 1, o comando funciona perfeitamente. Onde posso estar errando? Além disso, aparecem alguns warnings do tipo:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Provavelmente o erro ocorre porque você está tentando armazenar múltiplos valores em um vetor. Mas é difícil dizer sem uma amostrados seus dados. Como são os dados em tamamostra? O que é o objeto bons? Forneça um exemplo que possa ser replicado.